# How do I reset qBittorrent settings to default?

Tags: 14.04, configuration, qbittorrent

How can I reset qBittorrent settings to default? I couldn't find any *Reset* button in the settings. Can anyone suggest a better way to do that?

Comment: this probably isn't what you want; but a last-choice option may be `dpkg-reconfigure qbittorrent`  (will reset a package back to as-installed settings; note: i have no idea if it resets all settings for qbit-torrent)

Comment: @guiverc That actually *won't* work, because the relevant settings are per-user. [They're stored in `~/.config/qBittorrent` for each user.](https://askubuntu.com/a/980573/22949) Also, are you sure `dpkg-reconfigure` even resets systemwide settings for applications? I have never heard of `dpkg-reconfigure` reinstalling [conffiles](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles) for *any* package, though it does often modify them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

qBittorrent stores its settings in `~/.config/qBittorrent`, where `~` is your home directory. To clear the settings, you can remove or, better, rename that directory. **You should expect that this will cause qBittorrent to forget all your current torrents, though the actual *files* in them will remain intact.** I recommend making sure qBittorrent is not runnning before proceeding.

Since occasionally qBittorrent can remain running in the background after it seems like you've closed it, you can run this command to see if it  is running, if you think it might be. It will output a process ID if it is, or nothing if it is not:

```
pgrep qbittorrent
```

To rename `~/.config/qBittorrent` from the command line, run:

```
mv ~/.config/qBittorrent{,.old}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
cd ~/.config
mv qBittorrent qBittorrent.old
```

There are other ways, of course, but either of those work. Whichever you use, it renames the `qBittorrent` directory with a `.old` suffix. You don't need to replace `~` with anything when you type it on the command line. The shell expands it automatically to the name of your home directory.

If you really want to *remove* the directory, which I suggest against doing, then you can do that this way:

```
cd ~/.config
rm -r qBittorrent
```

If you prefer to rename or remove it using Nautilus (or another graphical file browser), then open up a file browser window in your home directory. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files and directories, so you can see the `.config` directory. Go into it and find the `qBittorrent` directory; then rename or delete it. (Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> again will re-hide files and directories whose names start with `.`.)

Next time you start qBittorrent, a new `~/.config/qBittorrent` directory will be created with fresh (default) settings.

Comment: One reason to ensure qBittorent isn't running when you do this: some apps write out their current configuration when exiting (qBittorent may not be one of those, but better to be sure). Learned this the annoying way when editing Terminator configuration.